# How to deal with predictors with no variability (i.e. ceiling floor effect) in linear models?

Tags: r, regression, lm, lme4

I want to test the effect of 4 numeric predictors on the DV in a linear model, however one of these predictors has no variability (i.e. ceiling effect). Should I remove this or use a sepcific linear model?

Comment: If a variable is constant, that is it assumes the same value for every observation, then it is useless in regards to prediction or interpretation. You can easily drop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a question better suited to cross-validated, stats or DS since it isn't primarily about coding.

Nevertheless I can point you in the right direction.

Firstly it depends on the exact nature of your variable. You say that is no variability/variance which would mean it is constant. Assuming your DV is not constant, clearly there is no correlation or effect and the variable can be removed because it has no impact (e.g. if all my test subjects are male, SEX is a useless test variable and will predict nothing).

However if you simply mean it has a small variance or is bound by some lower or upper threshold (e.g. never rises above X) than that is different.

The best answer to this is always to calculate multiple models and simply compare.

If a model including all variables is better than one removing the specific variable, it is of course valuable to keep it. Use r² and significance of predictors to track that and keep in mind that your variable could be useful as a suppressor variable even if it does not predict DV by itself.

Finally about model selection. You already assume that the relationship of predictors and DV is linear but maybe that isn't true or at least not for all variables. You could test that assumption and work from there. But switching between linear models is unlikely to affect the outcome and no linear model is better than another in detecting a relationship between an almost constant predictor and a DV.